# How to make a html slider always full

Tags: javascript, html, web

My goal is to have a slider refill itself when someone tries to lower itself but for some reason none of the code in my if statement will run.

```js
//Keeps the slider full
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange"); //Creates variable for slider position   
var output = document.getElementById("demo"); //Creates variable for outputting Value
output.innerHTML= ("Value:") + slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = ("Value:") + slider.value;
};   

//Raises the Value of slider if it isnt full
if(slider.value != 100){
  console.log("Slider isnt full");
  slider.value++;
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Loading Title...</h1>
    <p>
      <h2>My Awesomness:</h2>
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="100" class="slider" id="myRange"/>

      <div id="demo"></div>
    </p>
</div>
```

PS: I have also tried a while loop but thast didnt work so for now im just trying to get an if statement to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [Timing Event](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp), in this case setInterval will do nicely.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ahicks090/pen/bveMyy)

```
    //Keeps the slider full
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange"); //Creates variable for slider position   
    var output = document.getElementById("demo"); //Creates variable for outputting Value

    var tick = setInterval(function() {

        output.innerHTML= ("Value:") + slider.value;

        slider.oninput = function() {
          output.innerHTML = ("Value:") + slider.value;
        };   

        //Raises the Value of slider if it isnt full
        if(slider.value != 100){
          console.log("Slider isnt full");
          slider.value++;
        };
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, did you even call the JavaScript file in the HTML?

Second, JavaScript is run in a linear fashion. Since nothing in your code is in a loop, everything will run exactly once, when the file is loaded. You need some kind of loop or delay so the code runs every time the slider is changed.

Another thing-I would suggest using some form of a document ready function so your code doesn’t break.